# What is pro/con of having big ES index or several small ES indexs on same data?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

If I have documents like 1T and I want to query **the whole documents** every time.

What is pro/con of having just ***one big index (shard=100)*** or ***multiple small indexes (shard=100/index_num)***? 
I will use 100 shard anyway, but should I split to smaller indexes so that aggregation or other heavy requests could be distributed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two concepts here that you should understand -

1. Sharding - Sharding is where we divide our data into various partitions and assign one partition of entire data to a seprate shard. Each shard can run on any different machine. This way we can delegate our work to different machines. Say we have 10 Million documents and 10 machines. We set a shard of 10 and creates an index. When we complete writing this 10 Million document to this index , each million document will go to a different shard. And hence we will have 10 shard , with each shard having one million documents each. The advantage of this architecture is that , when you actually search the documents , it happens parllely in each each shard. As in this case ,each shard has its own machine , we are able to utilize all 10 machines at once for searching and hence achieve maximum performance out of 10 machines.
2. "**One index having 10 shards is the same as 10 indices having one shard**" - What actually counts is the number of shards. Index name is just an abstraction build over shards. Even if you execute search on multiple indices or single index , the performance is determined by number of shards the search has actually executed on.

By sharding , you are distributing all heavy operation like search and aggregation to various machines. If you are sure there wont be new documents at later point of time ,  and if you have 1T of documents and say 100 machines , the best approach would be to create a single index with 100 shards and then index the data in there.

Ideally one shard per machine is the best approach.

**Answer to the comment**

A single shard itself uses concurrency to the maximum. Hence it doesn't make sense to use multiple shards on same machine. An index is a collection of similar documents. In a different scenario , its partitioned based different logic to capture the distributed behavior better. For eg: , lets say  i am storing the logs data of free subscribers in an index with only 2 shard but i might store this same data for paid users in a separate index with 10 shards. So that the performance of paid user is much better. So index can be though as different sets of documents , that has different semantic meaning.

So to answer the comment , different index are different sets of information having different semantic meaning. It can be seen something similar to database in SQL. Hence i might store my bank transaction information in one index and my grocery purchase information in another index.

Comment: Thanks.Good description.Why do you think "one shard per machine is the best approach" and then what is the point of having multiple indexes?

Comment: Answer to comment added in the answer.

Comment: "A single shard itself uses concurrency to the maximum. Hence it doesn't make sense to use multiple shards on same machine."
I don't really get this sentence.Are you saying that each shard has it own thread pool?
I think each shard actually has one execution thread for searching.
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/engine/internal/InternalEngine.java#L737

Comment: Each node has its own threeadpool and associated queue which can be fully or partially used by any shard in a machine depending on the tasks it has to do.

Comment: I see.I think having multiple shards for the index of each nodes make sense as it is essentially IndexWriter or IndexReader and can be scaled when using the multiple threads.

Comment: I don't feel the same. Each shard is a separate lucene instance. And no matter the number of shards in a node , it would be sharing the same thread pool. Multiple shards for same index in same machine  is a good idea , if you want to scale in the future . as number of shards of an index can't be changed.